# .each method block leaves a hash after end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

im following the tutorial on http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ and im on chapter 10.

ive noticed after i do a .each method block it leaves a hash of all the items in the block. why is it doing this? its not on the pictures in the tutorial..

ex:

  <%= @users.each do |user| %>
- <%= user.name %>
  <% end %>

i have included a screenshot of what happens with the hash at the end[image].

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to print the first line

```
<%= ... %>
Should be
<% ... %>
```